# Displaying details for clicked element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm building a contacts app and I want to be able to show the details page for a specific element when it's clicked. I'm trying to pass the details of the clicked element up to the callback function that changes the page display, but I can't seem to grab the one I'm referring to. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Here's the component with the elements I want to be able to click:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class ContactItem extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    // console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div
        className="item-div"
        onClick={() => this.props.changeDisplay(this.props.contact)}
      >
        <img
          className="item-image"
          src={this.props.contact.smallImageURL}
        ></img>
        <div className="text-div">
          <h4 className="item-header">
            {this.props.contact.isFavorite === true ? (
              <span className="emoji-span">&#11088;</span>
            ) : (
              <span className="other-span"></span>
            )}
            {this.props.contact.name}
          </h4>
          <p className="item-text">{this.props.contact.companyName}</p>
        </div>
        <hr></hr>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to click on this div and then display the selected item's details.
Here's the component with the callback function I'm calling from the child element:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import ContactList from "./components/ContactList";
import ContactDetails from "./components/ContactDetails";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      contacts: [],
      displayContact: false,
      activeContact: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchContacts();
  }

  fetchContacts = () => {
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/e32o6")
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(contacts => {
        this.setState({
          contacts
        });
      })
      .catch(alert);
  };

  changeDisplay = contact => {
    console.log("got here");
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      displayContact: !prevState.displayContact,
      activeContact: contact
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.displayContact ? (
          <ContactDetails
            contacts={this.state.contacts}
            activeContact={this.state.activeContact}
          />
        ) : (
          <ContactList
            contacts={this.state.contacts}
            displayContact={this.state.displayContact}
            changeDisplay={() => this.changeDisplay()}
            activeContact={this.state.activeContact}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The changeDisplay function should set the activeContact in state to be the one that was clicked, but when I try to pass along that info from the child component, it won't work. I think I need to pass the contact.id back to the callback function, but I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If your console.log(this.props) === undefined, try this:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
```

Comment: When I console.log(this.props) in the child component, it returns each individual element (contact). If I console.log(contact) in the callback function, it returns every item instead of just the one I clicked.